# Booting from USB and mounting a HDD is resulting in strange partitions

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, usb-drive, ntfs, fstab

I just built a new HTPC and to keep costs down I decided to use a USB 3.0 thumb drive as my boot drive.
I had got most things running pretty smoothly and my next task was to mount a 2TB storage drive on start up, link it to my Home folders and share it on the network.
So I added a new line in fstab and restarted... opened Disk Utility to see if it was successful and found my 2TB HDD partitioned into 5 parts including one that was 18446743 TB (-611,910,040,576 bytes)!
I reformated the drive and ran 'mount -a' and it seemed to work this time but I couldn't link my Home folders to the equivalent folders on the HDD.
Did a restart and then my HDD was partitioned weirdly again.

The line I added fstab:

```
/dev/sda   /media   ntfs    0     0
```

My questions are:
1. Why is my HDD getting partitioned on restart?
2. Could the HDD be dodgy? Disk Utility says it's healthy.
3. Is running Ubuntu from a USB going to be more trouble than it's worth? It's a bit slower than I had expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problem was that I didn't have a partition table on the HDD even though it was only 1 partition.
Used gparted to format the drive again and then updated fstab now everything works smoothly.